# Start countdown with 3 second interval when reached to specific section in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```
  useEffect(() => {
console.log(window.scrollTo)
console.log(textInput.current.offsetTop);
```

}, [textInput,])

[enter link description here](https://www.playground.it/case-studies/armani-brandbook)

see bottom of this website same as countdown I want to make is there anyone with idea

Comment: I think Intersection observer will be helpful for your use case. Have a look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: It would be better if I get related tech examples to help  but thanks

Comment: https://spacejelly.dev/posts/how-to-trigger-a-function-when-scrolling-to-an-element-in-react-intersection-observer/

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intersection-observer

@Shreedhar Hegde tnx brother for giving me some idea

Answer (score 0):

```
// hooks
  const { ref: targetRef, inView: isVisible } = useInView();

const [countdown, setCountdown] = useState(3);

 useEffect(() => {

    let interval: any;
    // clearInterval(interval)

    if (isVisible && countdown === 0) {
      // @ts-ignore
      router.push(`/case-study/${parseInt(id) === 12 ? 1 : parseInt(id) + 1}`)
      setCountdown(3)
    }  
    
    if (isVisible) {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        setCountdown(countdown - 1);
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      setCountdown(3)

    }

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };

  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [isVisible, countdown])
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intersection-observer

https://spacejelly.dev/posts/how-to-trigger-a-function-when-scrolling-to-an-element-in-react-intersection-observer/

example and packages here.. try it

Comment: ok i will give the example after implementing on my website

Answer (score 0):

You can use Intersection observer and few hooks to make this work. For example, I have a hook named useInView() that uses IntersectionObserver object and returns true if some element is in view or false if not. More about [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

useInView() hook:

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
       
    const useInView = (element, rootMargin) => {
        const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);
    
        useEffect(() => {
            const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
                ([entry]) => {
                    setIsVisible(entry.isIntersecting);
                },
                { rootMargin },
            );
            if (element.current) {
                observer.observe(element.current);
            }
    
            return () => observer.unobserve(element.current!);
        }, []);
        return isVisible;
    };
    
    export default useInView;
```

How to make this work:

- First you need a useRef() hook to attach it to acomponent that you want to trigger the timer when user scrolls down to it.
- Pass ref object to useInView() hook as an argument so you can utilize IntersectionObserver.
- Create state with useState() so you can change state when timer is done
- Create useEffect() and add value from isInView() as a dependecy so you can trigger side effect when component is in view.
- In effect hook, set a timeout so after 3 seconds you can set your state to true
- Render your component when your condition is satisfied

```
    const componentRef = useRef(null);
    const isInView = useInView(componentRef, '0px');
    const [timerDone, setTimerDone] = useState(false);
    
    useEffect(() => {
       setTimeout(() => {
          setTimerDone(true);
       }, 3000);
    }, [isInView]);

    <div ref={componentRef}>
       { timerDone && <Component /> }
    </div>
```